# why c() does not working in this recursive function in R?

Tags: r, function, recursion, unique

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAxkV.png)

I know there exists function 'unique' which works similar to what I want to make, but I want to make this function.
I want this function finally returns 'result' which contains unique elements of input vector.
But I don't know why this function's result is totally different from my expect.
Why c which is to combine before result and new unique element is not working.
Please tell me how to fix my code.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, could you please include the code to your question as text within the question? You can mark it as code by selecting it and clicking the curly brackets in the menu bar of the editor.

Comment: Please paste your code for the function here rather than giving a link to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you expect might be something like below, where `result` should be an argument of `m_uni`:

```
m_uni <- function(x,result = c()) {
  if (class(x)=='numeric'| class(x)=='character') {
    if (length(x) <= 1){
      return(result)
    } else {
      if (x[length(x)] %in% result) {
        x <- x[-length(x)]
        m_uni(x,result)
      } else {
        result <- c(result,x[length(x)])
        x <- x[-length(x)]
        m_uni(x,result)
      }
    }
  } else {
    return('This function only gets numeric or character vector')
  }
}
```

such that

```
> m_uni(x)
[1]  0  4  5 -2
```